# Django Rest Framework returns: "a valid integer is required"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I created a react form using django with the rest framework in the background.
If i leave the integer field empty during form submission i get the following error from the rest api:

```
"a valid integer is required"
```

The problem is that this field is not required for the user to fill in and using a default of 0 doesn't work either since some people will type in a number and then change their mind and empty the field again.
So what i'm trying to do is when the field is empty the form sends null instead of an empty string.
I should propably mention that i'm using [formik](https://formik.org/docs/overview) to build my forms.

models.py

```
PriceRangeMax = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

FacilityUpdate.py

```
                            <Field name="PriceRangeMin">
                                {({ field, form }) => (
                                    <label className="mt-3 block">
                                        <span className="text-gray-700">Price Range</span><br></br>
                                        <input
                                        {...field}
                                        type="number"
                                        className="mt-2"
                                        style={
                                            form.touched.PriceRangeMin && form.errors.PriceRangeMin ? (
                                                { border: '2px solid var(--primary-red)'}
                                            ) : null
                                        }
                                        />
                                    </label>
                                )}
                            </Field>
```

serializers.py

```
class FacilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Facility
        fields = (
            "id",
            "Name",
            "FacilityDescription",
            "ListingVerified",
            "mainimage",
            "AdministratorCell",
            "FeaturedVideo",
            "PriceRangeMin",
            "PriceRangeMax",
            "is_owner",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "ListingVerified", "user")

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.user == user
```

views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.generics import (
    ListAPIView,
    RetrieveAPIView,
    UpdateAPIView,
)
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.mixins import ListModelMixin, RetrieveModelMixin, UpdateModelMixin
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import GenericViewSet

from users.models import Facility
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny, IsAuthenticated

from .permissions import IsFacilityOwner
from .serializers import FacilitySerializer, UserSerializer

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class FacilityUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsFacilityOwner]
    serializer_class = FacilitySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Facility.objects.all()
```

Comment: can you add your serializer and view

Comment: added both above

Comment: did u use "makemigrations" and "migrate"?

Comment: yes i used both

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use
`python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate`

and update your serializer as below

```
class FacilitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    is_owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Facility
        fields = (
            "id",
            "Name",
            "FacilityDescription",
            "ListingVerified",
            "mainimage",
            "AdministratorCell",
            "FeaturedVideo",
            "PriceRangeMin",
            "PriceRangeMax",
            "is_owner",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "ListingVerified", "user")

    extra_kwargs = {
        "PriceRangeMax": {"required": False}
    }

    def get_is_owner(self, obj):
        user = self.context["request"].user
        return obj.user == user
```

Comment: I just added this and migrated and it resulted in the same error

Comment: are you sure that comes from backend?  test DRF endpoints see if really comes from backend

Comment: I believe it is a problem caused by the frontend react part. The api only send me the error  response. I can submit the form just fine if i use the test interface on the url of the api and submit there without adding anything to the field.